# SWT Listen to Combo close

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm struggeling with the SWT Events.

Is there a way to get notified when a `Combo` is closed? I need to know when it is closed and the selection didn't changed.

I noticed that there is an event type `SWT.Collapse`, but as far as I know this only for `TreeItem`s (http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch01lev1sec3.html)

I would be pleased if someone can give me an hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the list of available `Events` for a given `Widget` on the [Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FCombo.html) page. The `Event`s for `Combo` are:

> **Events**:
>
> DefaultSelection, Modify, Selection, Verify, OrientationChange

If you are just looking for a way to find out if a new item was selected, just listen for `SWT.Selection` and compare it to the last selected item. `SWT.Selection` is only called when an item actually is selected, not if the `Combo` is opened and then closed by loosing the focus:

```
combo.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
    {
        String currentSelection = combo.getItem(combo.getSelectionIndex());
        
        if(currentSelection.equals(oldSelection))
        {
            // Same item selected
        }
        else
        {
            // Different item selected
        }

        oldSelection = currentSelection;
    }
});
```