# SWT combo MouseDown event is not triggered properly

Tags: java, combobox, swt, mouseclick-event

I am using a SWT combo which on mouse down event will show a calender pop-up when clicked first time and hide the pop-up when clicked second time and so on.

```
 mCombo.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
     public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                   showCalendar();
     }
  });
```

When I click on text area the MouseDown event is triggered every time fine. But when I click on the arrow in the right corner MouseDown event is triggered for first time and not second time.

Please let me know any solution to get rid of the issue.

Comment: What platform is this? Since the SWT implementation relies on native APIs the platform is important.

Comment: @yash Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have a look at this question: [SWT Listen to Combo close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047837/swt-listen-to-combo-close).

The `Combo` doesn't support events for the "close event". If you can use `CCombo` instead, then you can just listen to `SWT.MouseDown`, since this is fired on the arrow as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    CCombo combo = new CCombo(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    combo.add("First");
    combo.add("Second");

    Listener listener = new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    };

    combo.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
    combo.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```